# How to make ROS enabled Quadrotor with raspberry pi?

Tags: quadcopter, ros, raspberry-pi, simulation, gazebo

I am working on a project "ROS enabled Quadcopter", and am using hector_quadrotor package. But I am facing problems in Flight controller.

My world and quadcopter is running in gazebo but I don't know how to fly a quadcopter. There are many controller packages inside hector_quadrotor package.

Moreover, I want to run the same on real quadcopter with raspberry pi.

Anyone who can help me and send me some reference material.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* PrakharRastogi, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for **how to build something, how to accomplish something**, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Further, it's not clear what your problem is. Are you trying to fly a quadcopter in Gazebo? Are you trying to build your own quadcopter? These are two distinctly different questions, and both are **still** too vague to answer. *What is the problem you are having with the task*? ROS is generally associated with higher-level tasks such as signal acquisition and data processing; are you having trouble with ROS? If you could clarify your problem to a *specific, answerable question based on a problem you actually face*, as opposed to a, "How do I ___?", then we can re-open your question.